# EF - Error in converting type Dataaccess.Employees to ViewModels.Employee

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I have a view model class called Employee and a EF entity called Employees. If I write the below query I get an error stating that "cannot convert types, an explicit conversion already exists) I know how to solve this using select new ViewModel.Employee clause, but was wondering is there any concise way to resolve this ? Any help would be greatly appreciated -thanks

```
var selectedEmployee = (from q in emsCtx.Employees
                                                where q.Id == employee.Id
                                                select q).ToList().FirstOrDefault();
                       employeeData.Employees = selectedEmployee;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have two different types, even if they have the same properties, you need to do the mapping between them.  You can do this in many different ways, however a tool like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) can help.  AutoMapper is very good if you have types that are largely (or completely) similar in what public properties they have.

AutoMapper will allow you to make a mapping configuration between the two types and then map them.

For example, something like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<DataAccess.Employee, ViewModels.Employee>();

var dataEmployee = // data access

var viewModelEmployee = Mapper.Map(dataEmployee);
```